# How to create sqlite database in Unity (c#)?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I need to create sqlite database in Unity (C#) for android project, but can not find required information or tutorials.

I am following this link http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/743400/database-sqlite-setup-for-unity.html

But I get this error:

```
 Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/sqlite3.dll', expected 64 bit architecture (IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64), but was IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386.    
 Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection:Open()    
 Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection:Open()

 Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/sqlite3.dll', expected 64 bit architecture (IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64), but was IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386.
 Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3:Open(String, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum, Int32, Boolean)
 Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3:Open(String, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum, Int32, Boolean)
 Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection:Open()

 DllNotFoundException: Assets/Plugins/sqlite3.dll
 Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3.Open (System.String strFilename, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum flags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool)
 Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open ()
```

I am using Unity 5 (free version).

Are there any free plugins for sqlite database ?

Please provide me tutorials links if possible.

Comment: Since you mentioned C#, replaced `unityscript` tag with `C#`.

Answer (score 1):

This Error occurs when you use 32bit binaries on 64bit system.After Searching lot over the internet i found 64bit binaries +An Example project is also added. You can download them [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fv64how3y7a9rd3/AADqN3LNt7XYZHflV1GQE-9Wa?dl=0).

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial can help you for creating SQLite database in Unity using C#:
https://medium.com/@rizasif92/sqlite-and-unity-how-to-do-it-right-31991712190.

---

You can download the required Plugins from this [link](https://github.com/rizasif/sqlite-unity-plugin), which already contains the libraries for SQLite.

```
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Data;
```

Then for creating the database do the followings:

```
string dbConnectionString = "URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + dbName + ".db";
IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(dbConnectionString);
dbConnection.Open();
IDbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
dbCommand.CommandText = //write what you want here in SQLite syntax.
```

Then you need to execute the dbCommand.

for example for creating a new table:

```
dbCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + " ( "
        KeyRequiredLevel + " INTEGER, " +
        KeyPrice + " INTEGER, " +
        KeyPriority + " INTEGER, " +
        KeyIsLoacl + " BOOLEAN, " +
        KeyPercentage + " DOUBLE, " +
        KeyImageURL + " TEXT, " +
        KeyIsActive + " BOOLEAN )" ;

dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error said 'DllNotFoundException: Assets/Plugins/sqlite3.dll', have you put your sqlite3.dll file into Asset/Plugins folder? And you have to create this Plugins folder.

Comment: thanks for answering my questions,  sqlite3.dll file already in  Asset/Plugins folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one? Maybe this would help you:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-3d-android-sqlite-examples.114660/

Comment: thanks for answering my questions
I follow the example given in that link , it also give the same erroe:
Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/sqlite3.dll', expected 64 bit architecture (IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64), but was IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386.

Comment: You should use a version of sqlite3.dll according to your architecture. Maybe this link should help (it includes a x64 version of sqlite3.dll):

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/using-plugins-for-x86-and-x86_64-architectures-issue-with-sqlite3-dll-in-beta-9-solved.276719/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to use a library designed for Unity. Personally this is what I have been doing to handle multi-platform SQLite handling. I would highly suggest this library/wrapper

SQLite made easy for Unity3d http://codecoding.github.io/SQLite4Unity3d

I am currently in the process of improving upon that and making it even more easy to work with. However this is probably a good starting point!

GOOD LUCK!